# Jquery cycle2 carousel using divs not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle2

Im having issues with the cycle2 carousel plugin. [you can find my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AG6Dz/) and code at the bottom. In the fiddle it doesn't work completely but in Visual studio it only rotates to the right but when i go left(previous) and reach the first div it doesn't bring the last div to the front but just an empty spot.

here is the code:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="arrows">
                <div id="left">
                    <a class="slider" href="#" id="prev">
                        <img src="LeftArrow.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="right">
                    <a class="slider" href="#" id="next">
                        <img src="RightArrow.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentBox">
            <div id="section-home" class="cycle-carousel-wrap" data-cycle-fx="carousel" data-cycle-carousel-visible="7" data-cycle-slides="> div" data-cycle-timeout="0" data-cycle-next="#next" data-cycle-prev="#prev" data-cycle-carousel-fluid="true">
                <div class="box" style="background-color: blue;">
                    1
                </div>
                <div class="box" style="background-color: green;">
                    2
                </div>
                <div class="box" style="background-color: red;">
                    3
                </div>
                <div class="box" style="background-color: yellow;">
                    4
                </div>
                <div class="box" style="background-color: purple;">
                    5
                </div>
                <div class="box" style="background-color: orange;">
                    6
                </div>
                <div class="box" style="background-color: blueviolet;">
                    7
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="script">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('body').niceScroll();

            var tempWidth = 0;
            $('#contentBox .box').each(function () {
                tempWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
            });
            $('#contentBox').css({ 'width': tempWidth });

            $.fn.cycle.defaults.autoSelector = '.cycle-carousel-wrap';
        </script>
    </div>
</form>
```

the divs are floated left and have a width of 550px. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Add the class cycle-slideshow to the div with the id of section-home.

```
<div id="section-home" class="cycle-slideshow cycle-carousel-wrap" ...
```

Comment: This is not working properly. If you use the simple carousel efect and add the cycle-slideshow class it just convert it to the default effect.